# sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: unix

I am trying to add some file in a remote server by BigTuna (continuous integration tool), and it give me a error message. Any one have any idea how can I add that file to server?

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to 'requiretty' option on `/etc/sudoers`. If you have access to it, you might just remove that option.

If not, there are other ways as well. Probably you are doing something like `ssh user@host sudo do_something`. You can try to add -t option to allocate tty by ssh (so it would be `ssh -t user@host sudo do_something`).

Answer (score 0):

Your application use the sudo command in a no tty, you may bypass this by editing the file /etc/sudoers and comment this line :

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

Answer (score 0):

Command `sudo` fails as it is trying to prompt on root password and there is no pseudo-tty allocated (as it's part of the script).

You need to either log-in as root to run this command or set-up the following rules in your `/etc/sudoers`
 (or: `sudo visudo`):

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges.
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Then make sure that your user belongs to `admin` group (or `wheel`).

Ideally (safer) it would be to limit root privileges only to specific commands which can be specified as `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/program`